# DAGs and Equivalence Class of DAGs

Tags: machine-learning, modelling, dag, graphical-models, bayesian-network

I am learning DAGs and Equivalence Class of DAGs, I am reading the material by Prof. Campos Ibáñez here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume18/acid03a-html/node2.html

However, I don't understand this:

> "It should be noted that each structure in the DAG space is not always
>   different from the others in terms of its representation capability:
>   if we interpret the arcs in a DAG as causal interactions between
>   variables, then each DAG represents a different model; however, if we
>   see a DAG as a set of dependence/independence relationships between
>   variables (that permits us to factorize a joint probability
>   distribution), then different DAGs may represent the same model. Even
>   in the case of using a causal interpretation, if we use
>   observation-only data (as opposed to experimental data where some
>   variables may be manipulated), it is quite common for two Bayesian
>   networks to be empirically indistinguishable."

Could any please explain your understanding about this part? What are the differences between causal interactions and independence/dependence relationship? I'm new and a little bit confused to this.

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Note that DAGs are a more general concept than their use in graphical models. Your question is about the modelling, not DAGs per se. (<rant>Why, oh why do MLists seem to have to take over terminology that's older than their field?</rant>)